# Is it possible to sign multiple documents from one envelope at the same time?

Tags: docusignapi, e-signature

I have several documents in one envelope. It requires recipients to sign all the documents in the envelope.

I want to achieve that once I sign one document, the rest of documents would auto-signed. Is that possible? Hope you can help! Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does not support any form of auto signing or robo signing. All fields must be manually signed by the signer.

Answer (score 0):

So, Karan is correct, you can't auto-sign, but I don't think that's exactly what you asked.

If you have one envelope with 5 documents in it, and you only places tags (or signing elements or fields, the little things you actually sign like signature, initials, date etc.) only on the first of the 5 documents, then you won't have to worry about the other 4 documents. They would not have to also "be signed" and the envelope will be complete and you'll be done.

If that's what you meant - you can do this, no problem.